# Abstract Contracts In Solidity TypeError: No arguments passed to the base constructor. Specify the arguments or mark "AssetAcquisition" as abstract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, abstract, erc20

I had an issue with a solidity contract in which the error demanded I write my code as an abstract. Abstract means my code will be non-deployable.

*This is a contract that aims to transfer assets and acquisition. Just random stuff!*

````
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import './StringUtils.sol';

// @dev contract for rock,paper game0
contract AssetAcquisition is Ownable, ERC20 {
    string private _tokenname = "MATTokens";
    string private _tokensymbol = "MAT";
    address public _owner;
    uint randNonce = 0;
    uint modulus = 0;
    uint maxWaitTime = 100;

    struct Assets {
        address owner;
        address sender;
        address payable receiver;
        uint256 amountleft;
        uint256 datesent;
    }

    uint256 public _totalSupply = 1000000;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping(address => Assets) public assetstore;
    Assets newasset;
    Assets[] public assetstorage;

    event AssetTransferAndMergerEvent(address payable _companyaddress, address payable _mergeraddress, uint256 amount);
    event AssetTransferMergerDetails(address owner, address sender, address payable receiver, uint256 amountleft, uint256 datesent);

    constructor(address __owner, string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol) ERC20(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol) {
        _owner = __owner;
    }

 
} ```
````

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the constructor with this since it is expecting initial address.

```
constructor(address initialOwner) Ownable(initialOwner) ERC20(_tokenname, _tokensymbol) {
_owner = initialOwner;
```

}

Also for inheriting contracts this was the procedure

```
constructor(address _themergeraddress, address _initialOwner) AssetAcquisition(_initialOwner) {
themergeraddress = _themergeraddress;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity, a [Contract](https://solidity-by-example.org/constructor/) can inherit from another contract using the `is` keyword. In this case, the derived contract needs to specify the arguments for the base contract one of two ways:

```
contract Base {
    uint x;
    constructor(uint x_) { x = x_; }
}

// Either directly specify in the inheritance list...
contract Derived1 is Base(7) {
    constructor() {}
}

// or through a "modifier" of the derived constructor...
contract Derived2 is Base {
    constructor(uint y) Base(y * y) {}
}
```

[Example](https://solidity-by-example.org/constructor/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had issue with Ownable contract. Adding this constructor solved my issue. Though before I didnt need to initiate Ownable in constructor. I think it can be related to pragma version or blockchain  itself.

```
   constructor() Ownable(msg.sender) {

    }
```